# horizontally align magellan menu

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, magellan

I've been trying to horizontally align my anchor in my magellan but it keep showing one under the other as if it was a side menu locate above my content. What I need it to do is show in one line like a menu. Someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dd` are block level element by default stlye them inline-block or use float left.

Comment: are <dd></dd> similar to <li></li>?